# What is the React Hooks lifecycle for useEffect, useState, and useContext for multiple components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

TLDR: My problem is: `useState` in the context is not re-rendering in time for `useContext` from another component to get the updated state values.

*If you don't want to read the full explanation, a brief explanation of the 3 hooks in different components would be very much appreciated too. Thanks!*

TokenProvider: **context**

TeeToken, AccessToken, IdToken, and RefreshToken: **view components that display context**

App.js

```js
<TokenProvider>
  <TeeToken />
  <AccessToken />
  <IdToken />
  <RefreshToken />
  ...
</TokenProvider>
```

TokenProvider.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TokenContext from '../shared/TokenContext';

const TokenProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [teeToken, setTeeToken] = useState('');
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');
  const [idToken, setIdToken] = useState('');
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState('');
  const [tokens, setTokens] = useState('');
  // for data fetching logic
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState('');
  const [uniqueId, setUniqueId] = useState('');

  const loadToken = () => {
    const { oauth } = responseData;
    setUniqueId(responseData.reduxRequestId);
    setTeeToken(oauth.teeToken);
    setAccessToken({ decoded: jwt.decode(oauth.accessToken), encoded: oauth.accessToken });
    setIdToken({ decoded: jwt.decode(oauth.idToken), encoded: oauth.idToken });
    setRefreshToken(oauth.refreshToken);
  };

  if (responseData) {
    if (uniqueId !== responseData.reduxRequestId) {
      loadToken();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTokens({ teeToken, accessToken, idToken, refreshToken });
  }, [teeToken]);

  const context = {
    tokens,
    setResponseData,
  }
  return <TokenContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</TokenContext.Provider>;
};

export default TokenProvider;
```

I omitted a lot of the fetching part of the code for the sake of this question, but the point is I use `useState` to set all TeeToken, AccessToken, IdToken, and RefreshToken constant values from the fetched data and put them all nicely into tokens. Tokens is then put into the context.

I'm using `useEffect` because putting `useState` of tokens can not get the updated versions of all the various tokens because `useState` is an asynchronous action. So I'm waiting for the component to re-render, then tokens can get all the various updated values and re-render again to update the context.

However, the other component that uses `useContext` gets the un-updated version of the tokens. Please help how I could make the other component get the updated version of the tokens! Thanks.

EDIT: technically my issue can be solved by just passing all various tokens into context instead of keeping it in tokens, but I would still appreciate it if somebody could give me an explanation on the React Hooks lifecycle

Comment: Where does the `fetchedInfoX` values come from? That's a big thing. You should update your question with the asynchronous handling code.

Comment: @Fábio Batista It comes from the context as well. I've updated the code, thanks for the heads up